# install bootstrap on angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, installation, angular6

Hi i hav latest angular cli in my machine. i have tried to install bootstrap on angular project.
These are the steps i have followed .

1. ng new Demo
2. npm install bootstrap jquery --save
3. Then open the project in vs codein the angular.json file  i copy
   below code.

   "styles": [
                 "styles.css", "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
               ],
    "scripts": [
                 "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
                 "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" 
               ]

after that i run the project ng serve
i got this error msg.

> Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost: 4200, open
>   your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **  91% additional asset
>   processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file
>   or directory, open
>   'D:\Angular\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'

Comment: Have you tried building the app and running the serve command again?

Comment: I think the path you provided is wrong angular.json present in root of your project worksapce... So path you provided should be **"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"** instead of **"../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"** & same applicable to all other scripts in angular.json file

Comment: Thanks a lot Abinesh it is working . but glyphicon icons doesn't show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLI projects in angular 6 onwards will be using  `angular.json` instead of `.angular-cli.json` for build and project configuration.

Each CLI workspace has projects, each project has targets, and each target can have configurations.**[Docs](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4)**

```
. {
  "projects": {
    "my-project-name": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {},
            "demo": {},
            "staging": {},
          }
        },
        "serve": {},
        "extract-i18n": {},
        "test": {},
      }
    },
    "my-project-name-e2e": {}
  },
}
```

In your angular.json  add the file paths to the styles and scripts array in under `build` target with `./` instead of `../`

Boostrap 4 **[does not support](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components)** Glyphicons anymore, you can use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) instead:
Execute `npm install --save font-awesome` and addd file path to the styles array

```
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng6",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css","./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
               "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                       "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
          },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vikas error has gone  . but glyphicon icons doesn't show

Comment: @Lewis I have updated my answer accordingly, do Mark and upvote if it helped

Comment: Done .but  can't upvote. Because my reputation is less than 15.

Answer (score 0):

Place your command line on your project, then run:

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

Then, go your ide go to Angular.json and type at styles:

```
"styles": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css", "src/styles.css" ]
```

Do the same for the scripts:

```
"scripts": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ]
```